# XSL ignores my whitespace even with the <xsl:text> tag

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I'm making a header in my XSL code that includes multiple fields of information, i.e. "Name: Bob Birthdate: January 1 1900," etc. I enclosed them in  tags as such:

```
<xsl:text>    Gender: Male    </xsl:text>
```

But on the page, the whitespace around Gender/Male is being ignored. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question (+1), see my answer for how XSLT handles white space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to output a text file you should specify an `<xsl:output method="text"/>` as a child of the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element.

When treating output as HTML the parser might pack your spaces, if HTML output with non-breaking spaces is what you want you can use the `&#160;` non-breaking space entity (note that `&nbsp;` might not work since it's not an XML entity, unless you declare it yourself).

Comment: Declare it like this...

<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
 <!ENTITY nbsp  "&#160;" >
]>

Answer (score 10):

You may need the to use...

```
<xsl:text xml:space="preserve">    Gender: Male    </xsl:text>
```

Answer (score 2):

This not a strict XSLT question, as XSLT does not eat your white space. This transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <foo>
      <xsl:text>    Gender: Male    </xsl:text>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>    Gender: Male    </foo>
```

You are using HTML as the output? Then use non breaking space for whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
  &#160;Gender: Male&#160;
```

it represent whitespace in xsl like

```
 &nbsp;Gender:Male&nbsp;
```

in html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `&nbsp;` instead of spaces. To get more than 1 space

`<xsl:text><![CDATA[&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Gender: Male &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>`