# Need to handle white spaces in xml to html

Tags: xslt

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00EF034A" w:rsidRDefault="004165FE">
<w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/>
<w:r>
<w:t>one</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/>
<w:r>
<w:t xml:space="preserve">          11       8               15</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="004165FE" w:rsidRDefault="004165FE">
<w:r>
<w:t>two                             31</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

Hi all,
I need a guidance to write xslt template to reproduce the same content in node(w:t) in my output html(with white spaces in between). When i take the content of that node(w:t), the spaces(in between) are missing in output html.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: possible related/duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839730/xsl-output-method-text-including-whitespaces-in-xsl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724522/xsl-ignores-my-whitespace-even-with-the-xsltext-tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570280/question-about-xmlelement-innertext-and-whitespace

Comment: Your wrote *"When i take the content of that node (`w:t`), the spaces (in between) are missing in output"*. Unless you are using `fn:normalize-space()` that's not possible. So, you must post your stylesheet in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide more details, I guess you want

```
<xsl:template match="w:t">
  <span style="white-space: pre;">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

to ensure that HTML does not collapse any white space in between.